# Import d3 from unpkg

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, unpkg

I would like to import d3 from unpkg.com but I am not sure which file I should be importing.
What would be the unpkg equivalent of:

```js
import * as d3 from "d3";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will import d3 globally:

```js
import 'https://unpkg.com/d3@6.2.0';

// D3 defined globally
d3.select(...);
```

This will import it as a module (but make a lot of network requests for each module :/)

```js
import * as d3 from 'https://unpkg.com/d3@6.2.0?module';
```

Src: https://twitter.com/unpkg/status/905239560988221440